# Makefile No such file or directory

Tags: c, makefile

I'm trying to do some simple linked list practices to familiarize myself with C. I currently have the following makefile.

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall

app: linked_list.o app.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) linked_list.o app.c -o app

node.o: node.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c node.c

linked_list.o: linked_list.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c linked_list.h -o app
```

When I run it I get this:
    gcc: error: linked_list.o: No such file or directory

I've tried reordering node.o and linked_list.o, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compile the `.c` file, not `.h`; and get rid of `-o app`.

```
linked_list.o: linked_list.c linked_list.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c linked_list.c
```

Make sure to list both the `.c` and `.h` files as dependencies, both here and with `node.o`:

```
node.o: node.c node.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c node.c
```