# Makefile | Cleaning up after Make - Error: No such file or directory | Error: recipe for target * failed

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

> **Situation**

Attempting to cleanup after a Makefile compilation.

> **Errors**

These are the error(s) that I'm routinely receiving while attempting to conduct, one would believe to be, a simple cleanup operation.

**Errors:**

> **Command:**
>
> make linux

```
g++ Main.o CHARACTER.o ATTRIBUTES.o -o bin/release/Player.sh find *.o -type f -delete  
g++: error: find: No such file or directory
g++: error: f: No such file or directory
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-type’; did you mean ‘-pipe’?
```

> **Command:**
>
> make linux

```
g++ Main.o CHARACTER.o ATTRIBUTES.o -o bin/release/Player.sh rm -f *.o
g++: error: rm: No such file or directory
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-f’
```

> **Command:**
>
> make linux

```
g++ Main.o CHARACTER.o ATTRIBUTES.o -o bin/release/Player.sh clean
g++: error: clean: No such file or directory
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'linux' failed
```

> **Makefile**

```
linux: Main.o CHARACTER.o ATTRIBUTES.o
    g++ Main.o CHARACTER.o ATTRIBUTES.o -o bin/release/Player.sh clean

(alternate command attempt)
    g++ Main.o CHARACTER.o ATTRIBUTES.o -o bin/release/Player.sh -rm -f *.o

(alternate command attempt)
    g++ Main.o CHARACTER.o ATTRIBUTES.o -o bin/release/Player.sh find *.o -type f -delete

win32: Main.o CHARACTER.o ATTRIBUTES.o
    g++ Main.o CHARACTER.o ATTRIBUTES.o -o bin/release/Player.exe cleanWin

main.o: Main.cpp
    g++ -c Main.cpp

CHARACTER.o: src/CHARACTER.cpp include/CHARACTER.h
    g++ -c src/CHARACTER.cpp

ATTRIBUTES.o: src/ATTRIBUTES.cpp include/ATTRIBUTES.h
    g++ -c src/ATTRIBUTES.cpp

clean:
    rm -f *.o

cleanWin:
    del *.o
```

> **Summary**

Everything except the cleanup routine works apparently fine, however, once cleanup is attempted, I errors for functions that are definitely accessible throughout my OS, whether Win32 or Linux. Can't quite understand why these simple commands are routinely having issues.

> **Similar Posts**

Albeit, my issue is similar to the following post(s), their solution(s) apparently have no effect.

- [How to avoid “No such file or directory” Error for `make clean` Makefile target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21949237/how-to-avoid-no-such-file-or-directory-error-for-make-clean-makefile-target)
- [Makefile No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57531151/makefile-no-such-file-or-directory)

  - Cheers and thanks in advance for any feedback.

Comment: I don't get where does that `find` comes from...

Comment: There's no way you're getting that output from the makefile you've showed us.  Please provide the _actual_ makefile you're using, or at least the relevant sections.  Also you have sections named `Command` but you don't actually show the command that you typed; please show the make command you ran in your question as well.

Comment: I think those _are_ the commands OP typed. That's what I assumed when I answered anyway :-)

Comment: original commands are `make linux` and `make win32` under their respective OS's

Comment: @NobleCloud  Which command did you give to produce the `find` llne? Put the actual commands you gave at the command line in the question.

Comment: `make linux`, however, rather than `rm -f *.o` for the `clean` command, I had `find *.o -type f`... apologize for the omission.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58120833/edit) the question to clarify. Put the actual commands and the output they gave in the question. We can't help if we have to guess.

Comment: Didn't mean to confuse so many. Made some alterations. If there's further confusion please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding `find *.o -type f -deletefind *.o -type f -delete` and the other cleanup commands as arguments to `g++`. Put `;` between commands. Example:

```
linux: Main.o CHARACTER.o ATTRIBUTES.o
        g++ Main.o CHARACTER.o ATTRIBUTES.o -o bin/release/Player.sh ;
        clean
```

Note that this target, `linux`, doesn't actually produce a `linux` file. It will produce a binary file called `bin/release/Player.sh` which is a really bad name for a binary file. `.sh` is usually reserved for shell scripts.

Comment: With regards to your `make <target>` suggestion. I get that there are various ways to format a Makefile, however, would you mind pointing out a boilerplate, or "general method" or a "proper" way of formatting a rudimentary Makefile?

Comment: It's a different question really. Your should however make sure that the targets (like `win32`) actually produces a file called `win32` - or else it'll try to rebuild it every time.

Also make sure that the commands are valid. `g++ Main.o CHARACTER.o ATTRIBUTES.o -o bin/release/Player.sh clean`  seems invalid for example. `clean` will become an argument to `g++`.

Comment: @NobleCloud You also need a `<tab>` before the actual commands in the Makefile. It looks like you don't have that.

Comment: I do have actual single `<tab>` within the actual file. Not sure how else to illustrate it here. Apologies.

Comment: In addition to your remark on placing a terminator `;` or a semi-colon on the end of each statement. Can this be accomplished through a Makefile. Attempted myself, without much success, and can't locate documentation indicating its usage.